# ¿Como se puede hacer que un archivo guardo con la estructura de una pila?

Tags: archivo, pilas

Tengo una pila de 3 elementos y al cerrar el programa, este programa tiene que escribir un archivo vaciando los elementos restantes de una pila para después leerlos del archivo y sumarlos a la pila de la misma forma en la que fueron insertados .

Osea si en en la pila estan los elementos :

```
3
2
1
```

El archivo los tiene que guardar en ese orden, pero sin embargo no se como se puede hacer esto si el archivo va extrayendo  de la pila y agregando en el archivo . ¿Hay alguna forma para que guarde los datos en el mismo formato de una pila?

Comment: La solución es tener una pila auxiliar para invertir el orden de los elementos y luego guardarlos en el fichero

Comment: o guardarlos como estan, traerlos a una pila y despues invertir esa pila.. es pura teoria si no sabemos el lenguaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dijo Pablo Lozano, necesitas una pila auxiliar a donde tenes que pasar los datos de la original para no alterar el orden de los datos.

Como no especificaste el lenguaje en el que necesitas hacer esto, te dejo un ejemplo en java.

**Basicamente el programa pasa los datos de la pila original (sin alterar su orden a un archivo .dat Vos lo podes modificar a tu gusto, donde antes de pasar los datos al archivos, los podes sumar/restar o hacer cualquier otra operacion que quieras.)**

```
public class PasoPilaAlArchivo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declaro pila
    Stack <String> pilaOriginal = new Stack<String>();
    pilaOriginal.push("1");
    pilaOriginal.push("2");
    pilaOriginal.push("3");


    //declaro la pila auxiliar para no alterar el orden de los datos apilados
    Stack <String> pilaAux = new Stack<String>();

    //paso los datos de pila original al auxiliar
    while(!pilaOriginal.isEmpty()){
        pilaAux.push(pilaOriginal.pop());
    }

    // defino la ruta
    String ruta = "...definir ruta del archivo";
    // declaro el fichero (con la ruta y el nombre)
    File fichero = new File(ruta, "numerosPila.dat");

    // creo el flujo de salida hacia el fichero, si el fichero es NULL,
    // genera una IOexcepcion
    try (FileOutputStream flujoSalida = new FileOutputStream(fichero)) {
        System.out.println("Escribiendo fichero...");
        // el ciclo que llena el buffer con los numeros, si el buffer se
        // queda sin memoria,genera la
        // excepcion ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

        // paso el contenido del buffer al archivo a traves del flujo de
        // salida
        while(!pilaAux.isEmpty()){
            byte[] datos = pilaAux.pop().getBytes();
            flujoSalida.write(datos);
        }

        // cierro el flujo de salida
        flujoSalida.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e2) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: El buffer no tiene mas memoria, modificar su tamaño.");
    }

}
```

}